# Trying to use the EDSunriseSet SDK on Swift, but getting weird Sunset times

Tags: ios, swift, github

I am trying to calculate Sunset times for the user's location in my Swift app by using the EDSunriseSet SDK available on this link: https://github.com/erndev/EDSunriseSet

I am using the system's NSDate, but I am getting weird sunset times:

```
Date: 2015-11-27 19:47:58 +0000
TimeZone: America/Caracas
Local Sunset: <NSDateComponents: 0x7fa7716212e0>
    Hour: 13 //SUNSET AT 1PM MAKES NO SENSE
    Minute: 21
    Second: 10
```

My code is the following:

```
let today = NSDate()
let currentLocation = CLLocation()
        let sunrise = EDSunriseSet(date: today, timezone: NSTimeZone.localTimeZone(), latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        print(sunrise)
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Why are you passing `currentLocation.coordinate.latitude` for the `longitude` value?

Comment: I just realized that mistake and fixed it! However, I'm still getting the same information. Just edited my question

Comment: If you get the same result regardless of whether you put latitude or longitude for the longitude parameter, then something might be wrong with the coordinates in the currentLocation object.

Answer (score 1):

This implementation is working for me:

```
    let today:NSDate = NSDate()
    let calculator = EDSunriseSet(timezone: NSTimeZone.localTimeZone(), latitude: 49.195060, longitude: 16.606837)
    calculator!.calculateSunriseSunset(today)

    print(calculator!.sunrise!)
    print(calculator!.sunset!)
```

Output for Brno, Czech Republic:

```
2015-11-28 06:22:28 +0000
2015-11-28 15:00:20 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that currentLocation, initialized using CLLocation(), does not contain your actual geographic coordinates.  Print out the coordinates from the currentLocation object and see what they are.  Chances are they are 0.0/0.0.  You can provide latitude/longitude to the CLLocation initializer or use CLLocationManager to keep track of your location.  If you are not on a device that provides location services, you will need to make sure location is simulated appropriately.